# How to run .exe file with wine in a specific drive_c directory

Tags: wine, games, steam

I am playing around with Steam's new SteamPlay/Proton feature. I have installed the game, and now I want to install a third-party localization package, which comes in a form of self unpacking .exe file. The problem is that if I try to run this file, it starts to execute in context of `~/.wine`, and I need it to execute in context of `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/compatdata/<gameid>/pfx`, which steam has created to run my game. How do I specify where I want this file to run?

Sorry if my question is poorly formulated, I haven't really come to familiarity with wine, so I may confuse terms.